# How to read MS 97-2003 Worksheet through Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi, hssf

Am trying to read the .xls file(MS 97-20003 Worksheet) that is downloaded from our application through selenium webdriver. But am getting the following error:

"org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NotOLE2FileException: The supplied data appears to be a raw XML file. Formats such as Office 2003 XML are not supported"

And when I open it manually , am getting the following message :

"The file you are trying to open, 'ReportXX' is in a different format than specified by the file extension.verify that the file is not corrupted and is from a trusted source.....'.

By clicking on 'Yes' am able to open it and verify the content.

Please see the below code and let me know how can I resolve it. Thanks in Advance!!

```
InputStream ExcelFileToRead = null;
    Workbook   wb = null;
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\abcdef\\Downloads\\Report.xls");

    if (file.exists()) {

        ExcelFileToRead = new FileInputStream(file);

        wb = new HSSFWorkbook(ExcelFileToRead);
        System.out.println(wb.getNumberOfSheets());

        for (int i = 0; i < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {

            System.out.println("Sheet name: " + wb.getSheetName(i));
            Sheet sh = wb.getSheetAt(i);
}
```

Comment: That means that the file you are trying to download is not actually a xls. It could be a xlsx instead. So the problem seems to be in the server that generates that excel file.

Answer (score 0):

You can us the .jar file of JXL.jar which is more suitable for reading the .xls file of Microsoft excel sheet
The POI.jar which you are using is more supportive for the .xlsx format just try this.